# JBoss Weld : Inject different implementation for testing

Tags: java, jboss-weld

I would like to inject a different implementation in a bean, depending on the context. Here is the situation :

```
interface A{}

class AImplForTest implements A{}

class AImplForProd implements A{}

class B{
    @Inject A a;
}
```

In a test context, I would like the AImplForTest to be injected, while in a production context, this should be AImplForProd. B is the same class in the two contexts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used in practice but from theory you could use the `@Alternative` annotation.

From the [Weld reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#alternatives):

> Alternatives are beans whose implementation is specific to a
>   particular client module or deployment scenario. ... By default,
>   @Alternative beans are disabled. We need to enable an alternative in
>   the beans.xml descriptor of a bean archive to make it available for
>   instantiation and injection. This activation only applies to the beans
>   in that archive.

Comment: That's what I tried in a first time, but I had to locate my sources in a project, and the test (and the AImplForTest) in another project. But what does the term "archive" mean ? Maybe I don't really understand what it really means...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining each implementing class with @Named annotation and then inject the desired one by @Inject @Named("ForTest") A a; Hope this helps you if you didn't found any solution yet.

```
interface A{}

@Named("ForTest")
class AImplForTest implements A{}

@Named("ForProd")
class AImplForProd implements A{}

class B{
   @Inject @Named("ForTest") A a;
}
```